# The initial value problem $u_{x}+u_{y}=1,u(s,s)=1,0\leq s\leq1,$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was thinking about the problem that says:

> The initial value problem  $u_{x}+u_{y}=1,u(s,s)=1,0\leq s\leq1,$ has
>
> (a) two solutions,
>
> (b) a unique solution,
>
> (c) no solution,
>
> (d) infinitely many solutions.

My attempts: By using Lagrange's method, we see $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{1}.$ Hence we get, $x=y+c_1$ and $u=x+c_2.$ Now since $u(x,y)=x+c_2 ,$ we get by the given condition that $u(s,s)=1=s+c_2$ and so $c_2=1-s.$ So, finally we get, $u(x,y)=x+(1-s).$ Since $0\leq s\leq1,$we get infinitely many solutions for various choice of s. Am i going in the right direction? Please help.Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma51510/pde2.pdf) on page 16.

Comment: Thanks.It has been very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this PDE belongs to the PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde1201.pdf

The general solution is $u(x,y)=x+F(x-y)$ or $u(x,y)=y+F(x-y)$

$u(s,s)=1$ :

$s+F(0)=1$

$F(0)=1-s$

which does not make sense to have constant$=$function

$\therefore$ The initial value problem has no solution

Answer (score 2):

The solution of the differential equation is

$$ u \left( x,y \right) =x+{\it F} \left( y-x \right),$$

where $F$ is an arbitrary function. Now, apply the initial condition you have been given and see the [reference](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma51510/pde2.pdf) to finish the problem.

Comment: Thank you,sir. I have got it.

Comment: @learner: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Geometric approach**

$u_x+u_y$ is the derivative of $u$ in the direction $(1,1)$; that is,
$$
u_x+u_y=\nabla u\cdot(1,1)\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, $u_x+u_y=1$ specifies that the rate of change in the direction of $(1,1)$ is $1$.

Since the initial conditions specify $u(s,s)=1$, the rate of change in the direction $(1,1)$ is $0$. Thus, there can be no solutions.

---

**Another approach**

If we rotate coordinates so that $t=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $s=\frac{x-y}{2}$, the equation $u_x+u_y=1$ becomes
$$
u_t=1\tag{2}
$$
Thus, $u(t,s)=t+f(s)$ for any function $f$. Derotating yields
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2}+f\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\tag{3}
$$
To match up the initial conditions, we need that for all $s\in[0,1]$,
$$
1=u(s,s)=s+f(0)\tag{4}
$$
Again, this says there can be no solutions.

Comment: thank your sir for the explanation.

Comment: @robjohn: Hi RobJohn, is there really a difference between *a rate* and *a rate of change*? If they are the same thing, could we define both by saying *a rate/a rate of change is the ratio between two related quantities in different units*?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. A rate of change is a ratio of changes in two different quantities. The full discussion is beyond the scope of a comment; it might be useful to look at [Rate (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_%28mathematics%29)